# how to configure the bundle extension in Firebase on Flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I am currently trying to build the pipeline for serving a bundle of data in my project and I can't make it work even by reading the step by step documentation that firebase gives us.

I have followed the documentation and was able to create a bundle through this documentation:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/firestore-bundle-builder

But when I get to the documentation on [building and serving the bundle](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/firestore-bundle-builder#building_and_serving_the_bundle), things start to falling apart since I cannot find complete resources explaining how to implement it

So that is how I implemented it:

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      something
      "ignore": [
       something
      ],
      something
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/bundles/*",
        "function": "ext-firestore-bundle-builder-serve"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is it in the right level or not ? No idea... but that's what I did and I deployed it successfully.

Now, in the client integration part:

```
import { loadBundle } from "firebase/firestore";

// Download the bundle from the Firebase Hosting CDN:
const bundle = await fetch("/bundles/:bundleId");

// If not using a CDN, download the bundle directly:
// const bundle = await fetch('https://<location>-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/ext-firestore-bundle-builder-serve/:bundleId');

await loadBundle(bundle);
```

I do not know again how to implement it since the import give me an error, and every functions too.

I'd appreciate your help.
I am not new with firebase and I am not that bad at finding the documentation in order to understand but I don't know if the SEO is not good or the documentation not complete and will be completed but I failed to find it..

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you've opened the Cloud Shell, you're in a command-line environment where you can interact with your Firebase project and other Google Cloud resources. Here's what you can do to check the deployment status of your functions:

List Deployed Functions:
Use the gcloud command-line tool to list the deployed Cloud Functions for your project:

```
gcloud functions list --project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID
```

Or: Go to the Firebase Functions page and check if the function is in your Cloud Functions list.

Replace YOUR_PROJECT_ID with your Firebase project's ID. This will show you a list of all the deployed functions for your project. Look for your function in the list to ensure it's deployed.

If the function isn't listed, it means it hasn't been deployed yet. The firebase deploy --only hosting command only deploys the hosting configuration and any static assets in the specified public directory. It doesn't deploy Cloud Functions.

To deploy the function, you should use:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:ext-firestore-bundle-builder-serve
```

Once it's deployed, you can then check its status and logs as previously described.

After deploying the function, you should be able to access it through the URL you've set up in your hosting rewrites